# HTML select dynamically, other than if statements

Tags: php, html, select

I often need to make an `option` of a `select` combo box selected dynamically, like refining a search that needs to display previously selected values. I normally go through the options (in a for loop if getting from a DB), and check with an `if statement`:

```
$selected = 'Option 2';
foreach ($options as $value) {
    echo '<option ';
    echo ($selected == $value)? 'selected>' : '>';
    echo $value . '</option>';
}
```

Now this is quite a hassle to do that for every combo box, and it's more lines of code. Is there any quicker/more efficient way of selecting an option based on the value given. For example something like "Make `$selected` option selected", rather than running the if statement for every single option?

Comment: You can use jquery to select the values on page load.

Comment: that's right. I'm actually using that in a different page. I guess I should do that

Comment: Most tools that make this process easier perform a loop similar to the one you are using underneath.  The tricky part is creating an abstraction that suits all possible uses.

Comment: @SaranyaSadhasivam but that involves pieces of PHP variable access and jQuery in the same script, which sometimes gets quite ugly :(

Comment: Your solution looks fine to me, it's the one I use.

Comment: You could put it into a method taking an array and selected value to reduce repeated code.

Answer (score 1):

All you want is something to do what you are doing, but something that is reusable.

```
<?php

$options = array(
    '1' => 'Value 1',
    '2' => 'Value 2',
    '3' => 'Value 3',
    '4' => 'Value 4'
);

function generate_html_options($source, $selected = null) {
    foreach($source as $value => $string) {
        $attribute = $value == $selected ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
        echo sprintf('<option value="%s" %s>%s</option>', $value, $attribute, $string);
    }
}

?>

<select>
    <?php generate_html_options($options, 2); ?>
</select>
```

If elegance is what you are looking for, then PHP really has no end to how you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$selected = 'Option 2';    
foreach ($options as $Value) {
    if($Value != $selected) {
        echo "<option>" . $Value . "</option>";
    } else {
        echo "<option selected>" . $Value . "</option>";
    }
}
```

Comment: what if the value IS selected? your if statement doesn't handle those

Answer (score 0):

No if() case!

```
    $selected = 'Option 2';
    $options = array('Option 1','Option 2','Option 3');

    $str = "> ".implode($options,",> ");
    $replaced_str = str_replace("> ".$selected, " selected='selected' >".$selected,$str);
    $new_options = explode(',',$replaced_str);
    foreach ($new_options as $value) {
        echo '<option'.$value.'</option>'."\n";
    }
```

Comment: @mavili no if() case!